# Numpy deleting all rows with condition

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, delete-row

I have to edit a CSV file.

I can already import it and transform it into a 2D-Array

Now, my job is to delete all rows where, `0.0005 < array[i, 0]%0.0025 < 0.9995`.

(Basically, in the first column, are steps with a 0.0025 interval, and I need to delete all rows, where a step is accidentally bigger than it should)

I already tried the following:

```
length = len(data)
for i in range data:
   if 0.0005 < data[i,0]%0.0025 < 0.9995:
     np.delete(data, i, 0)
```

but it didn`t work. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues with your approach - first, you should not iterate on an array from which elements are deleted mid-iteration. Second, `np.delete` returns a new array and is not in place. Therefore, your call to this method does nothing. Also, there is a small syntax error in your range definition

Perhaps using multiple condition index

```
np.delete(data,(data[:,0]%0.0025>0.0005)&(data[:,0]%0.0025<0.9995),0)
```

---

We can verify a similar problem with an example: remove all rows where the first element `x` satisfies `1<x<4` (removed the mod as it doesn't matter for the example):

```
data = np.array([[i, 2, 3] for i in range(1, 6)])
>>> [[1,2,3],[2,2,3],...,[5,2,3]]
data = np.delete(data, (data[:, 0] > 1) & (data[:, 0] < 4), 0)
>>> [[1,2,3],[4,2,3],[5,2,3]]
```